# Starting a new Meteor.js project, can i use it?

Tags: javascript, meteor

Im starting a new project and i will be using meteor for the first time, maybe, was wondering first because haven't really find anything related with the topic, if there is any built-in package for a more advanced account/user-management, like user levels, memberships, payments, advanced profiles, avatars etc...

Answer (score 0):

I highly suggest you to take a look over the Meteor documentation.

It does have built in packages and Meteor has a lot of support from community so you will find packages for everything that you have mentioned in your question.

However, this is not Joomla so you will have to build most of the things by yourself.

> Written in JavaScript on the Node.js platform, Meteor is an open-source Isomorphic Development Ecosystem (IDevE) for efficiently and painlessly developing web and mobile applications. The Meteor ecosystem seamlessly integrates all the components (tools, libraries, databases, and frameworks [frontend and backend]) necessary for building and deploying applications.

Answer (score 0):

You can also take a look at Meteor Chef which provides several helpful tutorials: https://themeteorchef.com/tutorials